# Does the permission 'Mail.Read' really mean 'Mail.Read.All' in the Microsoft Graph API documentation?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm a bit confused regarding the documentation found at https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/permission_scopes

Mail.Read is listed twice but appears to mean different things both times.  The first instance "[a]llows the app to read email in user mailboxes" while the second "[a]llows the app to read mail in all mailboxes without a signed-in user".  The second sounds like it deserves the "all" qualifier and should not be confused with the first, since they do different things.

This is particularly relevant when the permission scope is a prerequisite (https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_messages).  What kind of behaviour can we expect?

My main question, then, is that am I right in thinking that there's no way to have delegated permissions that allow all mail to be read by the signed in user?  That, instead, we have to use the app-only permission?  The documentation gave me a sliver of hope that it was possible without app-only permissions but trial and error have suggested otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a separate `Mail.Read` permission for both Application and Delegated permissions.

First take a look at the section titled "App-only vs. delegated permissions"

> Permission scopes can be either app-only or delegated. App-only scopes
>   (also known as app roles) grant the app the full set of privileges
>   offered by the scope. App-only scopes are typically used by apps that
>   run as a service without a signed-in user being present.
>
> Delegated permission scopes are for apps that act on behalf of a user.
>   These scopes delegate the privileges of the signed-in user, allowing
>   the app to act as the user. The actual privileges granted to the app
>   will be the least privileged combination (the intersection) of the
>   privileges granted by the scope and those possessed by the signed-in
>   user. For example, if the permission scope grants delegated privileges
>   to write all directory objects, but the signed-in user has privileges
>   only to update their own user profile, the app will only be able to
>   write the signed-in user's profile but no other objects.

"Permissions not requiring administrator's consent" are delegated permissions, while "App-only permissions requiring administrator's consent" are the app-only permissions, which is why it shows up twice.

The next thing to realize is that when you get a delegated token, the permissions your app has will be the intersection of the permissions the user has, and the permissions granted by consent. Therefore, with the signed in user's token, you will only be able to read the mail that user has access to, the extent of which is captured by `Mail.Read.Shared`

```
Mail.Read.Shared
Read user and shared mail
Allows the app to read mail that the user can access, including the user's own and shared mail.
```

If you want to access the mail for all the user's in your tenant, then you must have a user account that has that level of access... or you need to use an App Only token which grants that scope of access.

```
Mail.Read
Read mail in all mailboxes
Allows the app to read mail in all mailboxes without a signed-in user.
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I'm not sure about that last point.  You're suggesting that an admin can access all the email in the tenant with only delegated permissions?  I think the documentation would agree, but I haven't had any luck.  This is the nature of my question with the documentation.  Am I just doing something wrong or is the documentation, in fact, sort of misleading on the point, and it's truly not possible except with app-only permissions.

Comment: I think "admin" here is an overloaded term. A Tenant Administrator is different than an Exchange/Mailbox administrator. Can you go into more details with the kind of user account you are trying to use, the mailboxes you are trying to access, and the specific errors you are getting?

Comment: I'm using a company admin account, which in my [understanding](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/About-Office-365-admin-roles-da585eea-f576-4f55-a1e0-87090b6aaa9d?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) is the same as a global admin.  I get 403 errors when I try to access any mailboxes.  Rather than diagnosing my issue, which might be off-topic, I would be satisfied with an assurance that it is, in fact, possible, and that I'm just doing something wrong.  Any help at all is appreciated really, I just don't know which direction to go in.

Comment: To my knowledge, Company Administrator is a global admin for Azure Active Directory, not Exchange. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-assign-admin-roles). You need to sign in specifically as a "Exchange service administrator". More about O365 Roles [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/About-Office-365-admin-roles-da585eea-f576-4f55-a1e0-87090b6aaa9d?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1).

Comment: This is an angle I hadn't thought of.  I appreciate your help.