# How to grant permissions as an admin to a group for an app in Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am looking for a way, as an admin, to grant permissions to an internal app on my Azure Active Directory only for a specific set of user (a group), without having to prompt any consent.

I want this app to have access to Mail.Read scopes on Graph API for a specific group of users only.

I manage to give access for the whole organization. (Clicking on the "grant permissions" button in the Azure Portal > Azure Active Directory > App Registration > MyApp > Settings > Permissions). How to limit these rights to  a specific group of users without having to prompt any individual consent ?

Answer (score 0):

> How to limit these rights to a specific group of users without having to prompt any individual consent ?

You could get it use **RBAC** in the portal.

Navigate to your app(not in the **App registrations**) in the portal -> Access control (IAM) -> Add, please follow the steps in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal#grant-access).

For more details about **RBAC**, you could refer to this link : [What is role-based access control (RBAC)?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview)

> I want this app to have access to Mail.Read scopes on Graph API

Go to your app in the **App registrations**, you could refer to the screenshot to choose the `Read mail in all mailboxes` option. The option means access to `Mail.Read`, refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42029389/does-the-permission-mail-read-really-mean-mail-read-all-in-the-microsoft-gra).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for these elements  @Joy Wang. I am still not very clear about where I should do that. Let me explain it differently : I have an application created on my Azure Portal, whith the Mail.Read scope as shown. Then I want my customer (a company) to grant access to my app (so i can have access in reading emails)  but only for a specific group of user. So what you say should be done on my customer side or on my side ? What I saw is that as soon as the customer admin consents (through OAuth flow), my app appears in their active directory as an Enterprise Application. But then... what's next ?

Comment: can you update me on the specific case I tried to developed ? Thanks !

Comment: @Sybic2001 Sorry, I have no experience on this specific scenaior, I recommend you to wait for another reply or ask it in another post.